# Facebook Sharing Window Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios4, sharekit

I am using Sharekit for Facebook sharing on my iPhone app. I had used used the following code for setting the app icon in the sharing window. It works fine except during first time login to Facebook.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

shareScore_ = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Share Message" contentType:SHKURLContentTypeUndefined];

shareScore_.facebookURLSharePictureURI = @"http://edibleapple.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/apple_rainbow_logo.jpeg";

[SHKFacebook shareItem:shareScore_];
```

During first time login it displays the image in http://google.com and if the user is already logged in it displays the correct image in icon_url. Is there any solution for this?

First Time Login ScreenShot:
[image]

Already Logged In Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @VilémKurz Screenshots Posted

Comment: It is a bug in ShareKit, I am going to fix it. Thanks for pointing at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in ShareKit - it is fixed now. Please update.